# Python: Cannot Assign Function Call

Tags: python

I am having a problem such as:

```
def function (number):
      for number in list:
          number = number + 1
```

For example function(1):
      for number in range(1,5):
          number = number + 1

Error come back as "can't assign function call"
I would like to use that variable as a value for further calculations.

Help!

Comment: something is a value that adds number in a loop.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ? your code is really...strange, are you sure you want to use number everywhere ? `list` is a python builtin, do not use it as a personal variable.

Comment: The code you gave would result in a completely different error message. Please show your actual code and the complete error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Cannot Assign Function Call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927/python-cannot-assign-function-call)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two problems. First, you are not naming your function or declaring it properly; you should do this:

```
def f(number):
   ...
```

Second, you are naming the function parameter `number` but on the next line you seem to be treating `list` as though it were the parameter. I think you mean to do this instead:

```
def f(list):
  for number in my_list:
  ...
```

Comment: And, as others indicated, it is also unwise to use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Don't name list as a local variable. It overrides the builtin list.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in python are defined using the `def` keyword:

```
def function_name(number):
  for number in my_list:
      number = number + something
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `def` to define a function

Comment: @Richee you need `def functionName(Number):`

Comment: @Richee: You've given three completely different versions of the way you defined your function, two of which do not compile. Programming requires strict following of the language syntax and an exact statement of your expectations. Random interpretations of either during coding or asking for help will not work. Trying to be more careful and following/learning the language rules would be of great help to you.