# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(maxalphabet):
    alpha = 'A'
    while ord(alpha) <= ord(maxalphabet):
        url = 'http://djpunjab.us/m/page/punjabimusic/'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plaintext = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)

        ord(alpha) += 1          # line no.14


spider('A')
```

why it is showing error on line 14

Comment: What do you expect `ord(alpha) += 1` to **do**. That is indeed not valid Python, because you cannot assign to `ord(alpha)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix "can't assign to function call" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927/fix-cant-assign-to-function-call-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to `ord(alpha)`, no. If you wanted to get the next letter in the alphabet, you'll have to do a little more work:

```
alpha = chr(ord(alpha) + 1)
```

That creates a new character from the ordinal of the current character, plus one.

Far more pythonic would be to use the [`string.ascii_uppercase` string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) in a loop:

```
import string

# ...

for alpha in string.ascii_uppercase:
```

This'll loop once over all uppercase letters in the ASCII standard; you can always use `break` if you need to limit the loop to `maxalphabet` at some point, or use a numeric limit (between 0 and 26) and use slicing. However you are not even *using* the `alpha` variable anywhere in your loop.