# change value of substring in python using math operator

Tags: python

I can't seem to find a solution to this faulty code.

```
nt(time_input[:2]) = int(time_input[:2]) - 12
```

`time_input` has the value of time in the hh:mm format. 
If the number exceeds 12:00, the number will be subtracted by 12 (am/pm).

I always get a syntax error like "Can't assign to function call." Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't assign to the result of a function call. Also, if you remove the `int(...)` on the left-hand-side, you can't assign an `int` to a slice. What exactly is it you want to do, and what is `time_input`, a `str`?

Comment: @tobias_k Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @tobias_k time_input is a string with the value of hh:mm (eg. 08:12). I have to convert these numbers to words. Eg. the value of time_input = 08:12 and i have to make a program that says what time it is in english. e.g It is twelve past eight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: "can't assign to function call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927/syntaxerror-cant-assign-to-function-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign to the result of a function call (`int(...) = ...`), and neither you can assign an `int` to the slice of a `str` (or, in fact, anything, since strings are immutable). Instead, you could use a format string to create a new string with the updated time and assign that time `time_input`:

```
>>> time_input = "13:45"                                                    
>>> f"{int(time_input[:2])-12:02}{time_input[2:]}"                          
'01:45'
```

Unless that's the only thing you want to do with that time, I'd strongly suggest parsing that string as a [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) and manipulating that instead.

---

> I have to convert these numbers to words. Eg. the value of time_input = 08:12 and i have to make a program that says what time it is in english. e.g It is twelve past eight.

In this case, *both* of the above is overkill. Instead, just get both the hours and minutes as integers first, and then subtract from the hours. No need to make that a string again.

```
>>> hrs, mns = map(int, time_input.split(":"))                             
>>> hrs %= 12                                                              
>>> hrs, mns                                                               
(1, 45)
```

Then, apply your "number to words" code to both, `hrs` and `mns`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test whether the HH part is greater than 12 and adjust accordingly. Here's how you could do that:

```
def fixtime(t):
    # assume that t is in the format HH:MM
    # no validation is performed
    hh = int(t[:2])
    return f'{hh-12:02d}{t[2:]}' if hh > 12 else t
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't understand why the f' is showing an error. Do I have to add a library?

Comment: You must be using a version of Python prior to 3.6

Answer (score 0):

```
time_input = "13:12" 
t_list = time_input.split(':')
str(int(t_list[0]) - 12) +':' + t_list[1] if int(t_list[0]) > 12 else time_input
```