# How to change function values inside an if loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from ufl import cofac, sqrt

def f(X):
  fx = sqrt(X[0]**2+X[1]**2)
  return fx
  
X = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
Y = f(X)
print(Y)

if f(X)<=3:
 f(X)=0.0
  
print(f(X))
exit()
```

The above function calculates the distance of a point from the origin. If the distance is less than 3 units, **I need to assign the value 0.0 to the function**.

But the above code gives me no difference in results before and after the "if" loop. How to assign values to functions inside an if loop?

Comment: "if" is not a loop.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to assign the value 0.0 to `Y`? `==` is comparison, not assignment. Look how you did assignment above.

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1,
Sorry, "if" is a condition statement, not a loop.
Do you mean "f(X)=0.0" is correct? That raises the error "SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question as asked, and the code as shown, do not make much sense. I recommend that you follow a Python tutorial from start to finish, and *make sure you learn proper terminology*, before trying to learn Numpy. In particular, "assign a value... to a function" is nonsensical, and as noted, `if` isn't a loop. If you mean "if the function would return something less than 3, it should return 0 instead", then the way to implement that is to put that logic *into the function* - fix the value of `fx` before `return`ing it.

Comment: If you mean "if the function returned a value that is less than 3, then `Y` should become `0` instead", then you do that by assigning `0` **to `Y`**. That means, `Y` goes on the left-hand side, and `0` goes on the right-hand side, thus: `Y = 0`.

Comment: The syntax error tells us that what you trying to do is wrong - at a fundamental Python level.  Making the function return 0 under certain circumstances, or changing its result, is quite another thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the `f()` function to return different results depending on the values in X.

```
def f(X):
  fx = sqrt(X[0]**2+X[1]**2)
  if fx > 3:
      return fx
  else:
      return 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mkrieger1 said; if you are trying to assign the value to f(X) you have to use `=` operator.

Moreover, you cannot assign the value to function, instead you can assign value to `Y` and print.

```
import numpy as np
from ufl import cofac, sqrt

def f(X):
  fx = sqrt(X[0]**2+X[1]**2)
  return fx
  
X = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
Y = f(X)
print(f(X))
if f(X)<=3:
  Y=0.0

 
print(Y)
```

Here, is the link:

[SyntaxError: "can't assign to function call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927/syntaxerror-cant-assign-to-function-call)

Comment: Hi @Talha Tayyab, "you cannot assign the value to function" is the comment I was looking for. So assigning only works if there's an auxiliary variable assigned to the function.

Comment: @user53927 Yes, I have edited my answer and put a link to a question for assigning a value to function.

Comment: @user53927 It seems like you have the right idea now. Please make sure you understand *what "assign" means*.