# When is it possible to assign to a function call in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

In C++, you sometimes have a situation where assigning to a function call makes sense--my understanding is that this is permissible when the function call returns an lvalue. So you might have:

```
some_function() = some_value;
```

In Python, it's not quite the same. Based on my understanding of the language, I would assume that there's never a time to assign to a function call. Yet if you try, you get a somewhat cryptic error message that suggests it may be possible. Here's a fairly minimal example (run with Python 3.10.8 and IPython 8.6.0):

```
In [1]: enumerate() = x
  Cell In [1], line 1
    enumerate() = x
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?
```

Because it says, "cannot assign to function call *here*", it seems implied there are cases where you might.

I'm wondering why that error message is as it is. Should it really say, "cannot assign to function call (at all)"? I expect this is the case, but I'm curious if there's some esoteric/special case that the error message is referencing when it says, "cannot assign to function call *here*".

I've tried searching this but can only find questions for people trying to resolve this error, for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927/syntaxerror-cant-assign-to-function-call). To be clear, I am not trying to resolve this error; I understand what's wrong (and there are quite a few things wrong) with `enumerate() = x`. I'm merely curious why IPython makes it sound like there may be some situation where it is appropriate syntax to say `some_function() = some_value`.

Is there something, or is it as I expect that this is just a confusingly written error message? Perhaps it just means "here" is the line/column where the error is? You'd think the arrow/carrot ^ pointing to it would be sufficient were that the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to a function call. It's just a confusing error message.

The error message comes from a [general rule](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Grammar/python.gram#L1114) for generating syntax errors for invalid assignments:

```
invalid_named_expression(memo):
    | a=expression ':=' expression {
        RAISE_SYNTAX_ERROR_KNOWN_LOCATION(
            a, "cannot use assignment expressions with %s", _PyPegen_get_expr_name(a)) }
    | a=NAME '=' b=bitwise_or !('='|':=') {
        RAISE_SYNTAX_ERROR_KNOWN_RANGE(a, b, "invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?") }
    | !(list|tuple|genexp|'True'|'None'|'False') a=bitwise_or b='=' bitwise_or !('='|':=') {
        RAISE_SYNTAX_ERROR_KNOWN_LOCATION(a, "cannot assign to %s here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?",
                                          _PyPegen_get_expr_name(a)) }
```

which covers more cases than just function calls. For example, if you write `1, a.b = 2`, you get

```
>>> 1, a.b = 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1, a.b = 2
       ^^^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to attribute here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?
```

saying `cannot assign to attribute here`, even though you can usually assign to attributes. That might have motivated the "here". Even in a case like this, the error message is still confusing, though - it shouldn't say anything about the attribute. It should point to the real problem, which is that this code is trying to assign to `1`.

Comment: Here's a link to the relevant [github issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87963#issuecomment-1093910331) that I found in the Python 3.10 changelog. The "here" does seem to be geared towards names or attributes.